# Outlook Add-In for Appointment not Enabled when opening another persons calendar

Tags: outlook, outlook-web-addins

I have a Outlook Add-In (The modern webbased add-in driven by a manifest) that is used when creating new Appointments. It works fine in my own calendar. However if i open another persons calendar and creates a new Appointment, then the Add-In button is greyed out. (I have full access to the other persons calendar)

Does anybody know if this is possible at all, and if so what must be done?

Comment: We have support for Shared Calendars for Outlook Add-Ins. It is likely that the add-in that you are using is not enabled for this feature. Here's a link with more information : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/delegate-access. If you own the add-in, can you try making the changes specified in the link and see if that resolves your issue?

Comment: Outook Add-ins Team - MSFT thank you for the answer. I have added the "SupportsSharedFolders" in my manifest, but when i create a new calender item in another persons calendar, the button is still disabled. You can see my manifest here: https://catering.visionpeople.dk/VisionCatering.xml

What is missing here?

Comment: Thanks for the additional information. Which Outlook client are you testing with (Windows, Mac, or Outlook on the Web), and what is the version number of that client?

Comment: Outlook on Windows:
Microsoft Outlook for Office 365 MSO (16.0.11328.20438) 32-bit

Comment: Delegate access is supported in builds >= 16.0.12127.10000, so your version number does not support delegate access, which is why you are seeing the add-in button disabled.

Answer (score 0):

Add-ins are installed per user profile.  Make sure the add-in is installed and enabled for this other user.

Comment: It is available in the other users calender. The problem is when i try to make an Appointment in that users Calendar from my Outlook